Is vegetable oil making us dumber?
In this video, titled "The $212 Billion Dollar Food ingredient poisoning your Brain", Joseph Everett makes the case that vegetable oils are lowering human IQ.
He cites professor Michael A. Crawford, a researcher who studies the role of lipids in brain development. He also cites several studies, like this 2015 study titled "The association between linoleic acid levels in colostrum and child cognition at 2 and 3 y in the EDEN cohort".
All of the citations in the video appear to be legitimate studies from expert researchers. However, I am wondering to what extent this is a well-replicated phenomenon with broad consensus, versus a fringe theory with some supporting evidence.

"Human IQ" is based on an average value of 100, so it's impossible for the collective IQ of humanity to have declined because the average will always be 100. Whether a 100 now is the same as a 100 from 25 years ago, though, I can't say.

It is not just the double-bonded fatty acids that matter (linoleic 18:2 and linolenic 18:3) but the products of these components when the oil is used for frying necessarily at fairly high temperature. So studies need to take cooking habits into account as well as the usage to which the oil is being put.

@F1Krazy. - look up the Flynn Effect. IQ has been going up over time and these tests need to be periodically re-normalized.

Note that the original cited study does not use IQ; see "Cognitive Assessments". It does control for a lot of variables like education, income, etc. The author of that video uses IQ, sells fancy salt water that claims to be good for you and conflates petroleum engine oil with vegetable oil.

I wrongly thought the discussion about IQ was just a poor word selection by the OP, and went to change it to "intelligence", but I checked the video and at 2m15 it does talk about a drop in average IQ of Massachussets children in 1979, so IQ is part of the claim. [I haven't watched the whole video.]

I saw the video a few days ago and it is very convincing and well made. But I found a few caveats: No mention of trans fats of other commonly used oils like palmitic acid. That is important since they can also significantly alter someone's brain just as linoleic acid could do and are also mostly artificial oils created by the food industry. Further, the claim that hearth diseases were rare before the 20th century could have different causes: A lot of people died young and those diseases tends to happen in older people. Also, hearth medicine was much more poorly developed than it is nowadays.

Hello, OP here. I mentioned IQ because the video mentions it, and claims that it's decreasing now between generations (implying that vegetable oil is a major factor in this decline). However, my questions is more about intelligence. I don't want to get bogged down in the semantics of "intelligence" vs "cognitive ability" vs "IQ" - if there's well-replicated evidence of any of those 3 declining due to vegetable oil, then I'll consider my question satisfied.

Even if intelligence had declined over time, tying it to vegetable oil as a cause would be a whole other matter.

@Oddthinking: well, around 3min he reveals that that (in MA) was due to leaded gasoline. However then he starts to talk about a new decrease in multiple countries after 1975. He keeps using "IQ" as the term though.

Verdict: Unlikely.
This video is full of misinformation, cherry-picking, and other forms of bias - please don't watch it. Even just focusing on the topical question, it's not entirely clear what the claim exactly is, but I'll just go with: "Seed oils are a significant contributor to a population-wide decline in human intelligence."
Intelligence:
Human intelligence, as approximated by IQ scores, has been gradually increasing for basically the entire history of IQ tests, a phenomenon known as the Flynn Effect. While the effect itself is well-established and mainstream, its causes remain controversial. I won't go through this literature as it's too much to cover, but a few points worth making are:

The cause is likely multi-factorial, with multiple dimensions that may change by location and time period.
The effect is generally accepted to be environmental, rather than genetic in origin.
A commonly hypothesized factor is improved nutrition over time (Rindermann, Becker, & Coyle, 2017).

Starting roughly in the 1990s, the effect partially reversed in some countries, known as the Reversed Flynn, anti-Flynn, or Negative Flynn Effect. It took some time for the trend to be distinguishable from statistical noise, so the first papers documenting the new trend appeared around the early 2000s.
Thus, charitably, we've had around 20 years to document and scramble for explanations of this emerging trend. However, given that we've had over 100 years to explain the rise in intelligence, and have yet to come to broad consensus, I'm skeptical that the fall will be solved faster, or be a simple 1-factor explanation.
It is also worth noting that if the Flynn Effect has an environmental cause, without changes to underlying genetics, then it should be expected that it would eventually diminish. Thus, many authors don't think that there is anything to explain (Pietschnig & Voracek, 2015; Dutton, van der Linden, & Lynn, 2016; Wongupparaj et al, 2023; Shakeel & Peterson, 2022; Pietschnig, Voracek, & Gittler, 2018; Flynn & Shayer, 2018; Trahan et al, 2014; also see Acosta, Smith, & Kreinovich, 2019).
Seed Oils:
As the video itself acknowledges, the view that vegetable oils and linonleic acid are unhealthy is not mainstream. Additionally, seed oils in particular have been disproportionately subject to conspiracy theories, so I think that some skepticism is warranted here. The video also overlooks how preparation (such as cooking and hydrogenation) affects the health impact of seed oils. Most notably, none of the major reviews or meta-analyses of the Reversed Flynn Effect (cited earlier) mention vegetable or seed oils.
Ironically, the video itself provides some evidence that seed oils are an unlikely cause of declining intelligence. This graph, likely sourced from Knobbe & Stojanoska (2017) - a poorly cited staple of seed oil myths - was featured at least 3 times in the video:

It shows that vegetable oil consumption has increased steadily during the same period of time that the Flynn Effect was observed - that is, it is more reasonable to conclude that seed oil caused an increase in intelligence, rather than a decrease. Note: I don't know how reliable this consumption data is, but other sources (eg, availability and absolute) seem to correlate.
Nutrition:
The study by Bratsberg & Rogeberg (2018) mentioned in the video, is well-received, and concludes that the causes of the Reversed Flynn Effect are also mostly environmental, rather than genetic. Virtually all of the same factors used to explain the increase in intelligence have been proposed to account for its decrease, including nutrition.
The Reversed Flynn Effect hits different countries at different times. The first large-scale study documenting a possible decline in intelligence in the USA by Dworak, Revelle, & Condon (2023) suggests the trend may have started there some time before 2006. However, the decline is not uniform across all facets of intelligence. As such, the authors note:

As the present study found differential slopes in mean cognitive
ability scores, it seems unlikely that quality of nutrition or health
would account for conflicting differences among the three-dimension
rotation tasks and the remaining tasks. Rather, we would expect to see
a reverse Flynn effect across all domains if the differences were due
to changes in nutrition or worsening health as cognitive processes
impacted by these variables are likely overlapping.

Studies in other countries have similarly suggested that declines are not uniform across all domains of intelligence or across different age groups, and therefore other factors are more likely causal of Reversed Flynn Effects (Woodley & Meisenberg, 2013; Platt et al, 2019; Lazaridis, Vetter, & Pietschnig, 2022; Pietschnig et al, 2023; Colom et al, 2023; Dutton et al, 2018; Vainikainen & Hautamäki, 2022).
Conclusion:

We can rule out seed oils accounting for declining intelligence as a mainstream hypothesis, well-replicated phenomenon, or broad consensus - it simply does not appear in the academic literature.
Poor nutrition in general is an unlikely candidate explanation for the Reversed Flynn Effect in the USA because it does not fit available evidence.


This question is somewhat unclear as to exactly what the claim being examined is.  There are two theories in scientific literature that are relevant here:

Human Evolutionary theory relating dietary availability of fatty acids to brain development
Nutritional theory relating modern dietary intake of fatty acids to brain function

The first is advanced by the Michael A. Crawford mentioned in the video in his quite famous paper Evidence for the unique function of docosahexaenoic acid during the evolution of the modern hominid brain, 1999.  This certainly was a valid hypothesis advocated for by reputable biologists.  However it was based on the idea that there was a "sudden, exponential growth of relative brain size in the last 200,000 yr or so" of human evolution, and that this is allowed by a change in diet to one rich in "good" fats, specifically docosahexaenoic acid from seafood which is most abundant omega‐3 fatty acid in cell membranes in the brain Clark et al. (1999)..
The primary challenge to this theory has come from modern genetic analysis of human evolution over the last few hundred thousand years.  This is illustrated by this paper, that proposes a web of hominid evolution across Africa over the last million years.  Evidence for much earlier tool use, such as this from 3.4 million years ago (writeup) also speaks against a sudden increase in mental capacity.
However this does not rule out an increased availability of these nutrients in some ancestor populations facilitating increased brain development within the hominid evolutionary web.
The second claim is more current, reviewed for example by Brain foods: the effects of nutrients on brain function, 2008.  This says:

a diet that is rich in omega‐3 fatty acids is garnering appreciation for supporting cognitive processes in humans and upregulating genes that are important for maintaining synaptic function and plasticity in rodents. In turn, diets that are high in saturated fat are becoming notorious for reducing molecular substrates that support cognitive processing and increasing the risk of neuro­logical dysfunction in both humans and animals.

It is worth noting that while many of the oils used in mass market processed foods have a very high omega 6/3 ratios, other vegetable sources of oils are compatible with fish sources.  This page on wikipedia has multiple food sources, and while sunflower oil has only omega 6 unsaturated fatty acids, flax seeds/linseed oil has four times as much omega 3 as 6, which is comparable to the oily fish which have ratios from 13 : 1 to 1 : 31 Omega-6 : omega-3.

A 2020 article agrees that linoleic acid can "adversely affect the brain".
"This review highlights the current state of knowledge on the role and metabolism of LA and OXLAMs in the brain.":

Abstract
Increased intake of omega-6 rich plant oils such as soybean and corn oil over the past few decades has inadvertently tripled the amount of n-6 linoleic acid in the diet.
Although LA is nutritionally “essential”, very little is known about how it affects the brain when present in excess.
This review provides an overview on the metabolism of LA by the brain and the effects of excess dietary LA intake on brain function.
Pre-clinical evidence suggests that excess dietary LA increases the brain’s vulnerability to inflammation and likely acts via its oxidized metabolites.
In humans, excess maternal LA intake has been linked to atypical neurodevelopment, but underlying mechanisms are unknown.
It is concluded that excess dietary LA may adversely affect the brain.
The potential neuroprotective role of reducing dietary LA merits clinical evaluation in future studies.
— Linoleic acid — good or bad for the brain? — National Library of Medicine

Even linoleic acid in breast milk can cause permanent damage:

Overall, studies have shown an adverse effect of maternal breast milk or dietary LA on neurodevelopment.
One study reported that a high maternal breast milk LA percent composition (>9.7% of fatty acids) was associated with reduced motor and cognitive scores in 2- to 3-year-old infants.
In the same cohort, maternal breastmilk LA percent composition was associated with reduced verbal IQ at 5 to 6 years of age.


There are a few more papers like that e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024320523009918 but the low citation counts for what shoiuld be a discovery on par with the influence of leaded gasoline (if we take the YT video at face value) makes skeptical this is a mainstream idea. If anything the latter paper paints a more mixed picture. LA might produce depression but help prevent Alzheimer's.

Also the Taha study you're quoting essential concluded that based on experiments on chicken. The other paper I mentioned cited it adding "but the mechanisms need to be elucidated".

The only real study on humans (cited by Taha) which claim a deleterious effect seems to be https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28081886/ Whether it's good science, IDK right now.

Among the study limitations they note that "In particular, we
were unable to adjust for maternal IQ as this was not available in our cohort". OTOH they used maternal education as a proxy. They also measured LA concentration at only one time point, but they note that it may vary over time.

Also, the main focus of that study was in fact whether (duration of) breastfeeding improves IQ (and they concluded that it does). That's also a pretty contested field.

It should also be mentioned that this article was already reviewed in the video, so doesn't add anything new.

@ArnonWeinberg says "It should also be mentioned that this article was already reviewed in the video, so doesn't add anything new." — And how many people that read this question will bother to watch that 25 minute video? I know I wouldn't bother to waste time on it. If something in the video is significant, quote it in the question.

I'm not disagreeing. I'm just pointing out that an answer that suggests that "this video may be correct because it says so" is not that useful.
